# replacing unknown variables in equation

Tags: java, string, variables, math, evaluation

So we have:

```
    String test2 = "12+x+43+y+32-100";
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    values.put("x", "3");
    values.put("y", "7");

    for (String key : values.keySet()) {
        if (test2.contains(key)) {
            String result = test2.replaceAll(key, values.get(key));
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> 12+3+43+y+32-100
>
> 12+x+43+7+32-100

While it should be:

> 12+3+43+7+32-100

Answer (score 1):

replace `result` with `test2`

```
            test2= test2.replaceAll(key,values.get(key));
            System.out.println(test2);
```

if you create a new variable `result` at every run you get a new string where only one variable is repleced

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, after finding x, it's been replaced with 3. Then it prints
12+3+43+y+32-100
Then again loop checks for letters. Then it finds y and replace with 7. But previous variable x won't be affected. So, 12+x+43+7+32-100 will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Java String objects are immutable. The method replaceAll() returns a new String object with the manipulation applied and your test2 object is unchanged.

So, you have to either apply the new modification in your result object or reassign the test2 object with the returned object.

```
for (String key : values.keySet()) {
    if (test2.contains(key)) {
        test2 = test2.replaceAll(key, values.get(key));
        System.out.println(test2);
    }
}
```